# Find the CDF and density for the ratio $Z=X/Y$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are iid?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are iid r.v.s where $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$. We are given $Z=X/Y$ and asked to find the CDF and density for $Z$.

I tried doing this using the multivariate transformation formula, where

$f_{W_1,W_2}(w_1,w_2)=f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)|J|$, but I ended up getting that $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$, which results in a negative CDF. I was hoping to see a different method of doing this. Any help appreciated.

Edit: Here is my work for obtaining my answer:

$Z=X/Y$; we then let $W=Y$ and $X=ZW$.
The Jacobian is then calculated to be $w$. That means we have:

\begin{align}
f_Z(z) & =\int_0^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(y)w\,dw \\[10pt]
& =\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}w \, dw \\[10pt]
& =\lambda^2 \int_0^\infty e^{-(z+1)\lambda w}w\,dw \\[10pt]
& =\frac 1 {(z+1)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: For future reference, you should post all your work to be proofread. We can't guess what your errors were.

Comment: stats.stackexchange.com anyone?

Comment: I didn't know stats.stackexchange existed! Thanks for pointing that out; I'll use it in the future. And I have posted my work to be proofread, as recommended. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, like I said, you should post your work to get proofread. This reduces redundancies and helps you get an answer faster.

The pdf seems fine.
As for the cdf,
\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)&=\int_0^z \frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\,dt\\
&=-\left.\frac{1}{1+t}\right|_0^z\\
&=-\left[\frac{1}{1+z}-1\right]\\
&=\frac{1+z-1}{1-z}\\
&=\frac{z}{1+z}
\end{align*}
for $z\geq 0$.

I don't see where it is "negative".

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you can say that $1/Y$ and $X$ are independent as well.
Now $W=1/Y$, then $f(w)=\lambda e^{-\lambda/w} (1/w^2), w>0$

$$Z=X/Y = XW$$
$$f(Z=z)=  \int_{x>0}f(X=x)f(W=z/x) \frac{1}{|x|} dx$$ from product distribution formula.
which gives
$$f(Z=z)= \int_{x>0}\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda (x+x/z)}(x/z^2) dx$$

Using formula for gamma function gives 
$f(Z=z)=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2} 
$